# JavaScript - Custom timestamp parsing with Datejs

Tags: javascript, datejs

i've got a custom timestamp which looks like this: "Jan 15 2020 11:11:50.000 +0000".
I need to transfer the timestamp mentioned above in an Epoch-Timestamp. I've tried it serval times - Right now my code looks like this:

```
oldTimeStamp = 'Jan 15 2020 11:11:50.000 +0000';
newTimeStamp = Date.parse(oldTimeStamp).toString('MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS Z')
console.log(newTimeStamp)
```

I have to use Datejs to transfrom the date.

Anyone got an idea how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Try to describe the problem. E.g. start by showing the output of your `console.log`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understood, this could help you transorming `oldTimeStamp` into a timestamp or UTC-string

```js
    oldTimeStamp = 'Jan 15 2020 11:11:50.000 +0000';
    newTimeStamp = new Date(oldTimeStamp).getTime()
    utcString = new Date(oldTimeStamp).toUTCString()

    console.log("Timestamp: ", newTimeStamp) // -> Timestamp:  1579086710000
    console.log("UTC: ", utcString) // -> UTC:  Wed, 15 Jan 2020 11:11:50 GMT
```

Using DateJS you can format the timestamp into any format

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. When I'm using your example the variable "newTimeStamp" has the value "NaN" - Do you got any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Did you use the oldTimeStamp variable? or did you use another one?

Comment: heres my code:

```timeStamp = "Jan 15 2020 11:11:50.000 +0000";

newTimeStamp = new Date(timeStamp).getTime();
newTimeStamp.toString();
  
Var1 = newTimeStamp;```

I just added the "toString"-Method. Without it, its the same behavior.

Comment: `var1 = newTimeStamp.toString();` try this. You didnt save the value returned by the `toString()`-method.